Couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so SoSource
I have a React Native application and the following is the output of npx react-native info for my application:
System:
    OS: macOS 14.2.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
    Memory: 121.06 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.04.08.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: Not Found
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK: Not Found
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377
    Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.22 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
    react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

This is my code in app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    entryFile: "index.js",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.mentortogether.mentorship"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 902007
        versionName "9.2.7"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('mentortogo-release-key.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'mentortogo'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "mentortogo"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "mentortogo"
            manifestPlaceholders = [bugsnagReleaseStage: "staging"]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "mentortogo"
            manifestPlaceholders = [bugsnagReleaseStage: "production"]
        }
    }

    def versionArray = getNpmVersionArray()
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + versionArray[0]*10000 + versionArray[1]*100 + versionArray[2]
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.11.0+'

    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook', module: 'hermes'
    }

    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native") {
        version {
            strictly "0.70.6"
        }
    }

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}

This is my build.gradle code
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.6.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        classpath('io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2')
        classpath('com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:5.+')
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral {
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven {
            url ("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://www.jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                        def file = new File("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/package.json")
                        def version = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file.text).version
                        details.useVersion version
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getNpmVersionName() {
    def inputFile = new File("../package.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
    return packageJson["version"]
}

def getNpmVersionArray() {
    def (major, minor, patch) = getNpmVersionName().minus(~/-.*/).tokenize('.')
    return [Integer.parseInt(major), Integer.parseInt(minor), Integer.parseInt(patch)] as int[]
}

In my application, I disabled hermes as I am using Jitsi in my application and Jitsi was not working as expected with hermes, after disabling hermes Jitsi worked fine but after publishing the app I started to get this error on Crashlytics, and the issue is only occurring on some Android 10 devices.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.bn.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.gu.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.hi.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.mr.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.bn.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.gu.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.hi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.mr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libhermes.so"

Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.bn.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.gu.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.hi.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.mr.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.bn.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.gu.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.hi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.mr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/org.mentortogether.mentorship-AMBt-GyVwMiPAlRVJO5lMA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libhermes.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
       at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.loadLibrary(SystemDelegate.java)
       at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:52)
       at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:30)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:774)
       at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary(HermesExecutor.java:25)
       at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java)
       at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary(HermesExecutor.java:23)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:393)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:343)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:96)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
       at org.mentortogether.mentorship.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:73)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1190)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6852)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:268)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)

I researched and tried all the possible solutions mentioned in the React Native Library repository for similar issues, but got no luck till now. This issue is impacting a lot of users of my application.

In relation to a lot of users being impacted, can you roll back to a prior version that does not have this problem?
